# Best practice for Hibernate lazy properties initialization in MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Let's say I use some entity, in pseudocode: `Article { id, author, text, date }` with all properties initialized lazily. I have repository method:

```
@Transactional
Article loadArticle(int id) {
  return articeRepository.find(id);
}
```

which is used by different controllers. `PreviewController` requires `author` and `date`. `ViewController` requires `text` and `date`.
Should I pass boolean parameters `initAuthor, initText, initDate` to `loadArticle()` method to call `Hibernate.initialize()` for each property there? Or should I move `@Transactional` to controllers' methods? What are the best practices dealing with lazy initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are aiming to have a highly performant data access layer, then you should keep one thing in your mind: every use-case is different thus needs different kind of data.

What I wanted to suggest with this is that you want to have different methods for different use-cases, which fetches only the data it needs.

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Fetching the entity relation with a fetch join
2. Create read-only projections

I prefer the latter as it clearly shows that it's for showing data rather than modifying it.

For projections, [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) can help as it has an out-of-the-box solution for it which is basically defining an interface.

If you use `Hibernate.initialize()` or any other way to trigger loading an entity relation, practically you will trigger a database query. If you think about let's say 100 entities, that means you will execute 101 queries. Use fetching or read-only projections.